# not getting expected output- python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the output I am getting for the code given below: -4 ,-4

The expected output: 8 ,-4

```
class arthemetic():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
        self.b=a

    def __add__(self, other):
         self.a=self.b
         self.a+=other.a
         return self
    def __sub__(self, other):
        self.a = self.b
        self.a-=other.a
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    a =arthemetic(2)
    b=arthemetic(6)
    print(*map(str,[a+b,a-b]))
```

Comment: You shouldn’t *mutate* the object within your `__add__` and `__sub__` methods but return new objects instead. By not doing that, the operations become non-deterministic. Both `a + b` and `a - b` return the `a` object after mutating it. That means that doing `a - b` actually changes the result from the previous `a + b`. Since both reference the same object, you get the same result in both cases.

Comment: @JeffUK In `print(str(a+b),str(a-b))` you are evaluating the results one by one. `a + b` is processed and then the result converted to a string; then `a - b` is processed and the result converted to a string. Then both strings are printed. In `[a + b, a - b]` both expressions are individually processed as well but the result is stored in a list. That list will be identical to `[a, a]` since both add and sub return a reference to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't *mutate* the object within your `__add__` and `__sub__` methods but return new objects instead. By not doing that, the operations become non-deterministic. Both `a + b` and `a - b` return the `a` object after mutating it. That means that doing `a - b` actually changes the result from the previous `a + b`. Since both reference the same object, you get the same result in both cases.

*<sub>-- from [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266825/not-getting-expected-output-python-classes#comment115385507_65266825)</sub>*